# Roles and Permissions in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to use active directory groups for website authorization? it's not just a group of users, managers, and admins. I have another dimension that is called location, so a user can be a manager in one location but an admin in another location, and can be not authorized at all in a 3rd location.

What's the best way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the location dimension as another set of groups and check the location groups and user type (users, managers, and admins) groups.

You can include Groups claim in your token as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes). You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["{group_id}"]
}
```

You can also define the location dimension as [App roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps). Then you can get the roles claim in the token:

```
{
  "roles": ["{location}"]
}
```

It might be clearer to combine app roles and groups.